# I have a procedure in VBA add-in, how to call it on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Assume I have an Excel add-in called test.xlam that contains this procedure:

```
Sub TestAbb()
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Hello world" 
End Sub
```

How do I call this procedure in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it in one of two ways:
1) Press Alt+F8 to see a list of all macros and then click run
2) Assign the macro a shortcut key combination - such as:

```
Sub TestAbb()      
'Keyboard shortcut = ctrl + shift + I
Application.OnKey "^+I", "TestAbb"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") = "Hello world"  
End Sub
```

And then simply press ctrl+shift+I (in this example) to run it directly